# adding an edit button in a foreach table in php

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, foreach, doctrine-orm

pls how do i write this correctly, I need to have an Edit icon for every row of my table.

```
    echo "<td>"<a href='editservice?edit=.$docrow->getId().'>Edit</a>"</td>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not stitching the string with the variable properly. Try this,

```
echo "<td><a href='editservice?edit=".$docrow->getId()."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td><a href="editservice?edit=<?php echo $docrow->getId()?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<td><a href="editservice?edit='.$docrow->getId().'">Edit</a></td>';
```